# Каким должен быть запрос для сортировки дат?

Tags: mysql, sql

Как выполнить сортировку дат используя только ORDER BY в следующем порядке:

- дата в будущем от ближайшей до самой дальней
- дата в прошлом от ближайшей до самой дальней

На данный момент SQL запрос выглядит так:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP(`time`) > TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
    CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP(`time`) = TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
    CASE WHEN TIMESTAMP(`time`) < TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC, time ASC
```

Но в прошедших датах порядок получается от самой дальней до самой ближней даты

Comment: У Вас что, поле `time` - строка, что ли?

Comment: нет time - DATETIME

Comment: А нафига тогда его надо преобразовывать в timestamp?

Comment: оно будет сравниваться по времени? если не преобразовывать?

Comment: Дата-время сравнивается полностью, а не кусками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Навскидку

```
ORDER BY SIGN(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, TIMESTAMP(`time`), TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())))
         ,ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, TIMESTAMP(`time`), TIMESTAMP(CURDATE())))
```

> time - DATETIME – `Strange Tin` 39 секунд назад

Тогда убрать преобразование в timestamp и использовать DATEDIFF().

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d2cf12f1c3a1b86b04b5c794c0f4038)